# angular mat-datepicker: error after select date

Tags: angular, undefined, mat-datepicker

This is my HTML for date picker. 
[image] 
 
I select date, and it throws this err which I cannot understand why.

[image]

Comment: Posting just images doesn't help, could you please provide a codepen or stackblitz link with your sample code.

Comment: Can you console log the $event you passing on to onChange function?

Comment: @LeelK
It doesn't reach that step.
I get param from closed method and it is undefined.

Comment: may you could create stackblitz for this or show the `onDateChange` function.

Answer (score 0):

I checked error out and found this moment issue. 
maybe it helps you to help me resolve my error. 
 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2i2O.png)

Comment: I add mat-datepicker & moment providers and this resolved my err.